# rich textfield editor in android phonegap application

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I am working on phoneGap android application in which I want to display bold,italic,underline,text align etc features in textfield.I implementing this by using ck editor jquery but it works fine in browser but it not shows in emulator and device also.So please help me in implementing rich textfield in android phone gap.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that CKeditor actually works correctly on android devices yet. While it does load, it has a number of quirks that prevent it from working "well".

In order to test for yourself, simply visit http://ckeditor.com/demo and play around with it.

I was involved with the IOS5 testing for CKeditor a few months ago - during that step-by-step testing I also sat down with 3-4 different android devices and ran the same tests I was running for IOS. Those tests did not turn out well, so I simply gave up. Those tests are outlined here:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=22880&sid=057e3d4af2a019cc2d22c177ec927b97

Possibly my experience is invalid because android devices vary wildly in their support for certain key features - but that is worth you knowing because you cannot plan on a widespread release as many devices (specifically Galaxy Tab) do not work well CKeditor.

If anyone has contradicting experiences I would love to hear them. Support was bad enough that I completely abandoned my android project in August and focused solely on IOS which has very good CKeditor support.